# Overlapping issue

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I am having an issue with overlapping items within a floating div. I must be applying the z-index wrong, but I've tried a few different things and I can't get the two items to overlap. I have the following code (note: topLink and topIconNew divs are actually pngs):

http://jsfiddle.net/jhacks/neskB/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="topIcon">          

<div class="topIconNew"></div>
<div class="topLink"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topIcon{

border:1px solid black;
background-color:gray;
width:28px;
height:40px;
float:right;
position:relative;
}

.topLink{
background-color:green;
width:16px;
height:16px;
position:absolute;
    top:14px;
    left:6px;
    z-index;300;
 }    

.topIconNew{
background-color:red;
margin:30px 0px 0px 18px;
width:10px;
height:10px;
position:relative;
    z-index:350;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

The HTML for the pngs (if it makes a difference):

```
<a href="xxxxx.html"><img src="xxxxx.png"> </img> </a>
```

**EDIT**** I've done it! Finally. Thank you for the help... upon seeing your code I saw the use of absolute and relative together. I now have a better understanding over the usage of those things and now instead of positioning things with padding/margins, I'm using (and correctly so I'd assume) positioning. I feel stupid for doing what I was doing.

Comment: What browser are you using where it's wrong?  Your fiddle has them overlapping for me, in Chrome 15.0.874.121

Comment: Your CSS has an error. There should be a *closing* brace in `.topLink` class, but instead you have another opening brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the edits, your question is much more clear now. I think this will satisfy your question.

http://jsfiddle.net/neskB/26/

Okay, so this makes a lot more sense now.

1. You have gray div floated right
2. You want to center a green div in this
3. You want a red div in bottom right of green div

First I would change your html structure to this.

```
<div class="topIcon">                 
    <div class="topLink">
        <div class="topIconNew"></div>
    </div>                    
</div>
```

Link will be positioned relative to its parent Icon.
New will be positioned relative to its parent, Link.

```
/* set topIcon to relative so that its child will be positioned relative to it */
.topIcon{     position: relative;   }

/* topLink is absolute positioned. We use top/left of 50% and negative margins to automatically center it */
.topLink{
    position: absolute;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    margin:-8px 0 0 -8px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%; 
}

/* New is positioned in bottom right of its parent */
.topIconNew{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made some edits to my original post. I can't believe I made that dumb error. Also, I was simply trying to get the div to move to a relative position within the div that contained it. I was misunderstanding the use of relative. Would relative still be the correct use here (and move it accordingly) or is there a position that could enable it to be positioned within it's containing div? Ultimately, I think I can fix this by being more clear with all my positioning... as I've edited in my main post. I think I should be able to fix this (I hope).

Comment: Okay, your update makes a lot more sense. Updating my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/neskB/26/

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually still want things a bit different than you have it (if you look at my newly updated code and remove either element from the html, you can see how they are position on their own). But I think what you have should enable me to get things working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, I think I misread it. I think if you pull the red div out of and below the green div it will do what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/neskB/28/

Comment: Thanks mrtsherman. I appreciate the help tremenously. Also, it seems that z-index isn't even needed here. Is that due to the order of the html elements?

Comment: Yes, that is because the ordering obviates the need for it. Elements that appear later in the html structure will sit on top of their parents or siblings.